# Solidity return uint[] show error invalid opcode

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping

I add data to mapping array by using add function. I want to show all data in array with function get_all like this code.

```
struct Client{
        uint x;
    }

    mapping(uint => Client[]) client;

    function add(uint id, uint _x) public {
        client[id].push(Client(_x));
    }

    function get_all(uint id) public view returns(uint[] memory){

        uint[] memory lastItems;
        for(uint i=0;i<client[id].length;i++){

                lastItems[i] = client[id][client[id].length-i-1].x;
           
        }
        return lastItems;
    }
```

I put sample data in function add like this.

```
10,11
10,12
```

when I run function get_all by set id to 10 it show error like this.

```
[call]
from: 0x5B3...eddC4
to: Test.get_last(uint256)
data: 0x84f...0000a
from    0x5B3...eddC4
to  Test.get_last(uint256) 0x7b9...b6AcE
execution cost  3000000 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)
input   0x84f...0000a
decoded input   {
    "uint256 id": "10"
}
decoded output  {
    "0": "uint256[]: "
}
logs    []

call to Test.get_last errored: VM error: invalid opcode.

invalid opcode
    
    The execution might have thrown.

Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

How to show all data in mapping array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are trying to set value at index of array that has no size:

```
uint[] memory lastItems;
```

Try to give it fixed length if you are going to push directly with **i** index, like this:

```
Client[] storage clients = client[id];
uint[] memory lastItems = new uint[](clients.length);
```

And it should work :)